# MYSQL How to exclude players mentioned more than once in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find  the average number of total games played in 2012 by players that received less than 2 offender reports. In on table I have offender_id and reported_date and in the other I have account_id, game_id and game_date.
So far I am able to find the average games played for 2012 across all accounts But cant figure out how to exclude those that have 2 or more offender reports. So I have

```
SELECT AVG(GamesPlayed) 
from (SELECT account_id, COUNT(*) as GamesPlayed FROM Games 
WHERE DATE(game_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31' GROUP BY account_id) nested;
```

That prints out the average of total games played. But how do I exclude those that have 2 or more offense reports. I have seperately been able to get

```
SELECT offender_id, COUNT(*) as GamesReportedOn FROM Reports GROUP BY offender_id HAVING COUNT(Reports.offender_id) >1;
```

which shows me the players with 2 or more reports but I dont know how to combine this with the above.

offender_id and account_id are the same

Comment: How offender_id could related  to account_id  ?

Comment: they are the same if thats what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldnt it be something simple like

```
SELECT AVG(GamesPlayed) 
from (SELECT account_id, COUNT(*) as GamesPlayed FROM Games 
WHERE DATE(game_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
and account_id not in (SELECT offender_id FROM Reports GROUP BY offender_id HAVING COUNT(Reports.offender_id) >1)
 GROUP BY account_id) nested;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Simple to you, but I have difficult wrapping my head around it and couldnt figure out how to do it without joins, ty

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inner join with the id having count < 2

```
  SELECT AVG(GamesPlayed) 
  from (
      SELECT account_id, COUNT(*) as GamesPlayed 
      FROM Games 
      WHERE DATE(game_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
      GROUP BY account_id
      ) nested
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT offender_id, COUNT(*) as GamesReportedOn 
    FROM Reports 
    GROUP BY offender_id 
    HAVING COUNT(Reports.offender_id) < 2
  ) t2  on t2.offender_id = nested.account_id
```

Comment: For some reason I get a different answer with this implementation in comparison to the above, I dnt know why though